# How to know in firestore when a collection have changes?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection who contains items of a restaurant menu, i want to know when a new item is added or have a change(price, name, description), because i want to notify this to the app and download this changes in a internal database.

I was trying to create a [firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=1) to modify a field called version and this way campare version in the app vs firebase version  of the collection but i really dont know how to work with firebase functions.

can someone give a recomendation?

Comment: You seem to be looking for [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cloud Firestore` is a flexible, scalable database which keeps your data in sync across client apps through `realtime listeners` and offers [offline support](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) for mobile and web applications.

So in order to know if something has been changed in your database, you need to attach a listner on a particular location. Assuming you have a collection named `cities` and a document named `SF`, plase use the following code. It's a straight forward example.

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        // see which fields changed
    }
});
```

Unlike Firebase Realtime database, Cloud Firestore has data persistence enabled by default. So there is no need to keep your data also in a internal database.

Comment: thanks a lot Alex, your answer give me a new idea about how to handle a offline mode off my app. because i want to bring changes only if there is a new one.